# Oracle Merge Append hint causes ORA-01400

Tags: oracle, merge, parallel-processing, append

I have an error I'm failing to understand. This is happening on some production code, but I created dummy tables to simulate the issue.

```
create table dl_test_nullable_src(col1 varchar2(20) NOT NULL, col2 varchar2(20) NOT NULL);
create table dl_test_nullable_tgt(col1 varchar2(20) NOT NULL, col2 varchar2(20) NOT NULL);

begin
for i in 1..10 loop
  insert into dl_test_nullable_src(col1,col2) values(i*100,i*300);
  insert into dl_test_nullable_tgt(col1,col2) values(i*100,i*300);
end loop;
commit;
end;
```

The below works

```
merge into dl_test_nullable_tgt tgt
using
(select * from dl_test_nullable_src) src
 on (tgt.col1 = src.col1)
when matched then update
set tgt.col2 = src.col2
when not matched then insert
(tgt.col2)
 values
(src.col2);
```

10 rows merged.

Now I add some parallel and append to direct path load any NEW records.

```
alter session enable parallel dml; 

merge /*+ append parallel(tgt,4) */ into dl_test_nullable_tgt tgt
using
(select * from dl_test_nullable_src) src
 on (tgt.col1 = src.col1)
when matched then update
set tgt.col2 = src.col2
when not matched then insert
(tgt.col2)
 values
(src.col2);
```

SQL Error: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("PBTUSER5"."DL_TEST_NULLABLE_TGT"."COL1")
01400. 00000 -  "cannot insert NULL into (%s)"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert NULL into previously listed objects.
*Action:   These objects cannot accept NULL values.

Even though this doesn't make sense on its own, it should not try to be inserting any records since everything that's in the SRC table is in the TGT table. The only way to bypass this is to also add col1 in the insert and values clause.

[Table Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv28c.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

as far as I can see this is described in MOS document 1547251.1 - and classified as "not a bug, but a feature". The difference is based on the evaluation of contraints in parallel and non-parallel execution.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback -  I'll go through the documentation. I guess it makes sense when taking into account how direct path load works.